# CSS3 Nested fixed position elements for dialog box

Tags: angularjs, css

I'm trying to use CSS with 'position: fixed' to create a dialog box. When I 'open' the dialog box in chrome I can see the 'dialogbox' in the dropdown where the markup of the fixed element is, but it is not rendered in the way I expect.

Chrome shows that the dialog is there and the position is correct, but the rendering is wrong.

I'm expecting fixed elements to be drawn relative to the viewport regardless of where they are in the DOM, and the z-index is larger than all other elements. What am I doing wrong?

[image: the 'fixed' element is not positioned over other elements in the screen, but you can see the overlay and parts of the dialog in the dropdown]

Comment: Make parts of your image scrollable so that we can inspect the `Styles` tab ♫

Comment: With the information provided, it is hard to find the culprit here. I would suggest moving the modal in your markup, either in the <div> tag that has the class .container, or as a direct child of the <body> tag, as the first tag. Also, check if you can click or mark anything in those tables while your modal is open, if you cannot, there might be some opacity issues going on. Can you post your code in a CodePen?

Comment: Fixed elements are positioned relative to the viewport only if you use the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left` properties to position them. If you don't, then the only difference you'll see is that they no longer take up any space in their parent element. Also, if the fixed element has an ancestor with a position other than static, the ancestor's z-index will effectively limit the fixed element's z-index relative to any elements outside the ancestor.

Comment: Moving the element as a direct child og body works, but I wanna know WHY. The selected element (the dialog) has top, bottom, right, left position set. Isn't 'fixed' supposed to mean positioned according to viewport?

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, you shouldn't use `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` all at the same time since `bottom` and `right` will have no effect when the other two are set. But, yeah, the `top` and `left` properties should position your fixed element relative to the viewport, so if they aren't doing that, then they and/or the `position` property are probably being overridden by some higher-specificity CSS somewhere.